# Importing my own .hy files and using their elements

Tags: import, hy

Suppose I have a file `foo.hy`, which looks like this:

```
(def friends ["Joe" "Mark" "Bob"])
```

And another file `bar.hy`, in the same directory as `foo.hy`, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env hy

(import foo)
```

In `bar.hy`, I'd like to refer to the `friends` variable defined in `foo.hy`. How would I do this? For example, I'd like to call `print` with `friends` from `bar.hy`, but I'm not sure how to do this (and all my attempts don't seem to make the Hy REPL too happy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(import foo)
(print foo.friends)`

Or, if you want to import `friends` into the current namespace, so you don't have to prefix it with `foo.`:

`(import [foo [friends]])
(print friends)`